# .remove() not working with ajax on success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have some html divs that are generated using jinja2 with this:

```
{% for student in students %}
<div class="item" id="{{ student.id }}_div">
   <div class="right floated content">
      <div class="negative ui button compact remove_from_class" id="{{ student.id }}">Remove from Class</div>
   </div>
   <i class="large user icon middle aligned icon"></i>
   <div class="content">
      <div class="header">
         <h3><u>{{ student.get_full_name }}</u></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="description">{{ student.email }}</div>
   </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the script I have for it which gets the parent divs id, and then tries to remove it using .remove().

```
$(".remove_from_class").each(function () {
$(this).on("click", function () {
    var id = this.id;
    var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    var set_id = url.pop() || url.pop()


    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/delete_from_class/',
        data: {
            'id': id,
            'set_id': set_id,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success == true) {
                var div_id = id + "_div";
                var parent_div = $(div_id);
                parent_div.remove();

            } else {
                alert("Student wasn't removed!");
            }

        }
    })
})
})
```

However the div isnt being removed, even though the success popup appears.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: because your value of variable **id** was changed, at the line **var div_id = id + "_div";** and your selector was wrong you are missing **#**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `#` to use `id` as a selector.

```
var div_id = "#"+id + "_div"; // Use # here
var parent_div = $(div_id);
parent_div.remove();
```

Or the better approach I would suggest here is to store `div` inside `.click` in some variable and then later use that.

```
$(".remove_from_class").each(function () {
$(this).on("click", function () {
    var $parentDiv = $(this).closest(".item"); // Save it here
    var id = this.id;
    var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    var set_id = url.pop() || url.pop()


    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/delete_from_class/',
        data: {
            'id': id,
            'set_id': set_id,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success == true) {
                $parentDiv.remove(); // And remvoe it here

            } else {
                alert("Student wasn't removed!");
            }

        }
    })
})
})
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for explaining the problem to me

Comment: I'm going to use the second one, but im going to make sure I understand all of it first so im off to do some googling! Will mark the answer as correct in 3min when I am able to

Comment: Note worthy, if you do not use the `var` keyword on your `$parentDiv` then you are actually declaring the variable in the global scope. See [MDN var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) under `Implicit globals and outer function scope` or [W3 JS Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) under `Automatically Global`. Best to not clutter your global namespace with local variables.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this

```
$('#'+ id +'_div').remove();
```